# Finding text within XML using nokogiri

Tags: xml, xpath

I am attempting to get a value from an XML file.

So I have parsed the XML to get the correct container using:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`:` is used to separate namespace prefix in an XPath expression. You rather need something like

```
//maskedcardaccount[contains(., '2345')]
```